# Hadoop: Data node not started, Logs show "Java bind exception (port in use)"

Tags: hadoop2

Data node service is not started on one of my Hadoop cluster.

Data node logs has the following information...

**Exception details on PC where datanode service is not started:**

> 2015-08-12 15:51:09,331 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: HttpServer.start() threw a non Bind IOException
>       java.net.BindException: Port in use: localhost:0
>               at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.openListeners(HttpServer2.java:919)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpSe
>              ...........................

**On successful Data Node PCs the Log looks like this**

> 2015-08-12 15:43:57,520 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 34958
>
> 2015-08-12 15:43:57,520 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
>
> 2015-08-12 15:43:57,619 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@localhost:34958

I have tried fixing the ports in hdfs-site.xml as explained in the [link](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-Win-1.3.0/bk_installing_hdp_for_windows/content/win-troubleshoot-2-2.html)

But this did not work. Please throw some light in fixing this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"localhost:0 "
please check your /etc/hosts ,most likely this file not set well

Comment: This was my problem. Needed to add this line to /etc/hosts: `127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost`

Answer (score 0):

I have uncommented the following line in `/etc/hosts` and everything worked fine.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem is due to the port is already used, hence **BindException** Thrown. to fix this issue follow the below steps.

**1.**

> run netstat -np command to know the port used with process id

**2.**

> Kill process id for the port which is already bind.

Comment: I have looked for ports that are in use with the command netstat -p. 

I did not find the datanode's port in use by any of the process...

Default ports of a data node are described in the link "http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/"


Thanks